# Attempt to use an object that has ceased to exist

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i have 1 site collection that has 4 subsites beneath it, all the 4 subsites have the same home page with the same page layout and master page and also web parts (with lists), i keep getting this error

> Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED

the following is the stack trace :

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.LocalizeText(String
>   bstrToLocalize, UInt32 lcid, String bstrDefaultResourceFile, Boolean
>   fIsXml) +0
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.LocalizeText(String
>   bstrToLocalize, UInt32 lcid, String bstrDefaultResourceFile, Boolean
>   fIsXml) +258
>
> > [SPException: Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist.
> >     (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))]
> >     Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
> >     +146    Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.LocalizeText(String bstrToLocalize, UInt32 lcid, String bstrDefaultResourceFile, Boolean
> >     fIsXml) +786
> >     Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.GetLocalizedString(String
> >     source, String defaultResourceFile, UInt32 language) +85
> >     DMA.Internet.Common.Helper.GetResourceValue(String resourceKey) +161
> >     DMA.Internet.WebParts.MunicipalElectronicServices.MunicipalElectronicServices.Page_Load(Object
> >     sender, EventArgs e) +464    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +95
> >     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
> >     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
> >     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
> >     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
> >     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
> >     System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> >     includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> >     +2936

here are my attempts:

1- double checked my code for any incorrect SP objects disposal,like `SPContext.Current.Site` and `SPContext.Current.Web` but everything looks fine (no disposal for the previously mentioned objects)

2- copied my Resource files to App_globalResources and used `HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject` instead of `SPUtility.GetLocalizedString` but no luck

Note: some web parts im using uses Custom Field Type (base type boolean), and if i remove this web part the home page works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is solved, it was a strange behavior that the exception is thrown at `Helper.GetResourceValue()` level, however,i was calling a method that fetches Events from a Sharepoint Events Calendar while setting `ExpandRecurrence = true;` and `RowLimit = 1;`,so just removing the `RowLimit=1;` solved the issue.